# Writing back a dependency property value to the view model in two-way binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I'm implementing a wpf control that provides some common binding between xaml and Google Maps running in a web browser. Currently, the bindings are one-way and are working fine.

What I need to do next is write back a value to the view model when two-way binding is specified. The property I'm starting with is the Google Map's zoom. When it's changed in the browser I can run js on the page that calls back to my C# code with the new zoom level.

What's the correct way to offer this new value to the DP such thas it will update the view model's zoom level if a two-way binding was selected?

My current code for the the zoom level DP:

```
#region ZoomProperty

    //Called from the web page
    private JSValue MapZoom_OnMapZoomChanged(JSValue[] arguments) {
        string zoom = arguments[0];

        //where do I set the zoom so that the view model bound property is updated?
        return null;
    }

public static readonly DependencyProperty ZoomProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Zoom", typeof(string), typeof(GoogleMap), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnZoomPropertyChanged), OnZoomPropertyValidate);

public string Zoom {
    get { return (string)GetValue(ZoomProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ZoomProperty, value); }
}

private static bool OnZoomPropertyValidate(object value) {
    return value is string;
}

private static void OnZoomPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    GoogleMap control = source as GoogleMap;
    control.SetZoom(e.NewValue.ToString());
}

private string zoom;
public void SetZoom(string value) {
    if (!googleMapPageReady) {
        zoom = value;
        return;
    }

    webControl.ExecuteJavascript(string.Format("setZoom({0})", zoom));
}

#endregion
```

Comment: As a note, you may also set the `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault` flag with another overload of the Register method to make a dependency property bind two-way by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm overlooking something, you just need to do:

```
private JSValue MapZoom_OnMapZoomChanged(JSValue[] arguments)
{
    string newZoom= arguments[0];
    this.Zoom = newZoom; // here
    return null;
}
```

The dependency property pattern is setup so that from the outside you can just treat Zoom as a normal c# property (setter and getter).  If you look at the setter for that property it calls [SetValue()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473(v=vs.110).aspx), which is on the DependencyObject base class and does the magic to notify the binding engine of the change (also see: [Register()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597502(v=vs.95).aspx))

**Update**

A simple way to prevent the change from sending the update to the map when the map was the one providing the change in the first place:

```
private bool IsMapUpdateSuppressed = false;

private JSValue MapZoom_OnMapZoomChanged(JSValue[] arguments)
{
    string newZoom= arguments[0];
    this.IsMapUpdateSuppressed = true;
    this.Zoom = newZoom;
    this.IsMapUpdateSuppressed = false;
    return null;
}

private static void OnZoomPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    GoogleMap control = source as GoogleMap;
    if (!control.IsMapUpdateSuppressed)
    {
        control.SetZoom(e.NewValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

This allows the DP value to change, process, and notify the binding engine as usual, but just prevents the call to SetZoom

Comment: I guess that's my confusion - do I need to guard against OnZoomPropertyChanged from being called again in this situation? The zoom value is coming from the map so it doesn't need to be set again.

Comment: The OnZoomPropertyChanged isn't called again, unless the value of the Zoom property did actually change.

Comment: What are you actually binding to in xaml?

Comment: I think my issue (first foray into DP) is that the DP for Zoom in the c# is a proxy value for the actual zoom (which is kept by the map.) I need to think about how to handle this.

Comment: I see - You're concerned about relaying the zoom change back up to the map after *it* is the one sending the change (and thus doesn't need the notification)?

Comment: Yes - that's it exactly.

Comment: Updated - see if that works, your first comment was almost correct.